# Does an Indian citizen need a transit visa for Thailand and China?

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, transit-visas, china, thailand

I am Indian citizen. I am travelling to Toronto, Canada. I do have Canadian PR but don't have any other country visa.

Do I need Bangkok transit visa? My layover is 8h.  Also, do I need transit visa for China? The layover is only 3 hours.

Itinerary looks like this:

Ahmedabad, Guj (SpiceJet) → Bangkok, Thailand (8h layover) (China Southern Airlines) → Guangzhou, China (3h layover) → Toronto, Canada

Comment: are you bringing any checked bags on your flight to bangkok and/or from Bangkok to China/Canada?   Also, which Bangkok airport code will you land in?  Which airport code  will you depart from?  (Should say in your ticket)

Comment: It is not enough to only post cities.  You need the airport codes, times, etc to get an accurate answer.

Comment: I am arriving to Bangkok in SpiceJet and I am bringing one checked bag with me. I will depart from AMD, India and will be landing in BKK airport at 00:40 on 3rd May and will continue journey to CAN, Ghangzhou at 08:40 on 3rd May through China Southern Airlines.

Comment: Also not clear:  are all the flights on a single flight itinerary?   Meaning you are going from `AMD > BKK > CAN > YYZ` on one ticket  (you didn't separately book `AMD > BKK` and `BKK > CAN > YYZ`)??

Comment: booked separately from AMD > BKK and BKK > CAN > YYZ

Comment: I think I will get visa on arrival at BKK as I am indian citizen.

Answer (score 2):

[Timatic](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements-results.aspx?NC=IN&NV=India&AC=CA&AV=Canada&DC=CA&DV=Canada&TC=TH%2CCN&TV=Thailand%2CChina&h=788daf2397bfbcf22031d1cf6647ec254963a6b6) says that you will need a visa for Thailand:

> **Transit - Thailand (TH)**
>
> **TWOV (Transit Without Visa):**
>
> Passengers transiting through Bangkok (BKK) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 12 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.
>
> **This TWOV facility does not apply** to passengers traveling on Angkor Air (K6) [...], **Spice Jet (SG)** [...] and VietJet Air (VJ).

However, you will not need a visa for China:

> **Transit - China (People's Rep.) (CN)**
>
> **TWOV (Transit Without Visa):**
>
> Passengers with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 24 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.
>
> This TWOV facility does not apply at Fuzhou (FOC), Huangshan (TXN), Mudanjiang (MDG), Shenzhen (SZX), Urumqi (URC) and Yanji (YNJ).

Since you're transiting at Guangzhou (CAN) and not at any of these airports, you can transit without a visa.

Comment: Indian nationals can get a [Thailand e-visa in advance](http://en.evisathailand.com/) (official site) or visa on arrival. With the specifics of this itinerary I recommend getting it in advance, to prevent any misunderstanding with the airline, as Timatic does not list the visa on arrival when putting in Thailand as a transit country (it does show with Thailand as a destination country).

Comment: The problem is that I am travelling tomorrow and don't have enough time. If I can get e-visa, can you provide any link where I can get e-visa?

Answer (score 0):

For the leg `AMD >> BKK` you may need a Visa On Arrival (VoA) for Thailand if you:

a) have any checked bags and you are changing planes such that you are on separate itineraries.

b) are switching airports (Bangkok has two airports Suvarnabhumi (BKK) and Don Mueang (DMK) ).

If `AMD >> BKK >> CAN >> YYZ` are on a single itinerary, then you can wait in the int'l terminal area without the need to get a flight.  Checked luggage will automatically be routed to the correct airplane.

If `AMD >> BKK`and `BKK >> CAN >> YYZ` have 2 separate tickets (and are **not** on the same itinerary), then you would need to check the luggage back in again at BKK.  This requires that you "enter" Thailand (clear immigration) and you'd need a VoA.   Good news about VOA which is explained below...

> The problem is that I am travelling tomorrow and don't have enough time. If I can get e-visa, can you provide any link where I can get e-visa?

I laid out some of this in [a previous answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/137299/), but I will copy it here:

You will need:

- Passport
- arrival/departure card (TM-6  will be attached to passport page when you enter)
- 1 passport photo 4cm x 6cm, although larger size may be accepted
- application ([TM-8](https://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/137299/), [[backup]](https://forum.thaivisa.com/topic/1096930-thai-cabinet-agrees-to-waive-visa-on-arrival-fee-until-october/))
- <s>Fee:  1000 baht for single re-entry and 3800 for multiple re-entry permit.</s> [VoA is free until October 2019](https://forum.thaivisa.com/topic/1096930-thai-cabinet-agrees-to-waive-visa-on-arrival-fee-until-october/).

**[VoA application can now be started online](https://www.immigration.go.th/content/online_serivces?click=1) ([Direct URL](https://extranet.immigration.go.th/voaonline))** to reduce wait times.

[image: Thai Immigration Visa on Arrival (VoA) online application]

There is also a place onsite to take passport photos, but I recommend having your own photos ready to save money/time.

---

In the future, try to ask visa/airport-related questions before booking the tickets and/or a few weeks out.  Asking at the last minute usually does not give the traveller any advantages.

FYI, the King Rama X's Coronation ceremony is between 04-06 May 2019.  At worst, it would add to the check-in time (should you need VoA).

---

In regards to `BKK >> CAN >> YYZ` @Mophotla answered this one thoroughly.  If you are not exiting the terminal areas and having to actually clear immigration/customs in order to catch the onwards flight, you have nothing to worry about in `CAN`

Comment: very well explained. Thank u so much.

Comment: you're right. I should have prepared earlier. However at the moment, the cost of this travel is very very high, more than diamond. Therefore, I was looking for cheaper option.

Comment: @PiyushP If the answer was useful, an upvote would be helpful :)   Also return here when the trip is complete and let u know what happened (edit your answer if comment is long)